# Why does this very simple array iteration not work?

Tags: php

I have the following array

```
 Array ( [0] => Please enter address line 1 
          [1] => Please tell us your first name 
          [2] => Please tell us your last name 
          [3] => Please tell us your email 
          [4] => You must tell us one phone number 
          [5] => Please tell us second applicants title 
          [6] => Please tell us second applicants first name 
          [7] => Please tell us second applicants last name )
```

I am looping through it as follows 
                `foreach($error_hash as  $value) 
                    {
                echo "error <li> $value <li/>";
                }`

Annoyingly I keep picking up blank lines

Please enter address line 1

error

Please tell us your first name

error

ect .......

Any input would be great

Comment: Maybe problem lies in other place ? is your array example print_r( $error_hash ) ? Is it all about this loop or you are doing somthing with $value ? Also check CSS styles for <li> or you forgot <ul> and errors landing somewhere else.

Comment: You should always use quotes around your strings, please..

Comment: That should be *????????* instead of *!!!!!!!!*

Comment: @Gordon: Had to look at revisions before I got it!

Answer (score 5):

Embed 'error' within the 'li' tags, so it won't produce extra output. Something like:

```
echo "<li> error, $value </li>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Watch your tag

```
<li/>
```

Maybe this will help:

```
</li>
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

I have checked. This is work.

```
$a[0] = 'Please enter address line 1';
$a[1] = 'Please tell us your first name';
foreach ($a as $b) {
    echo $b;
}
```